# Android onclick button timer

Tags: java, android, timer, onclicklistener

I want to update a method using timer and i want to do it when the user clicks on a button . But it only happens when the button is clicked and needs reclicking for it to happen again i want it to happen continuously after the button is pressed just once .

Comment: show what you had tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have the timer queue a new timer when it is finished.  or better yet use

```
Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)

Comment: it should be in comment.

Comment: This seems to be not a answer for his problem

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan theres no question mark in his statement.  If he is looking at how to run a timer at a fixed interval that will give him his answer.  His button press simply needs to start the timer for scheduleAtFixedRate ....